# Creating a feed of calendar events that users can subscribe to

Tags: calendar, feed

I know there is some way to create a feed of calendar events that users can add to their calendars and have new events be automatically added to their calendars. I don't know the name of the technology used and searching wasn't bringing up much.

What is the technology used for creating these calendar feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the thing I was looking for. It's called CalDav and uses the iCal format for data.

Some more info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV).